# Inheritance in Perl

Tags: perl

I have two classes, one is the base class(Employee) and the other its subclass which inherits it (Extend) the codes of which are shown below :

```
package Employee;
require Exporter;
our @EXPORT = ("getattr");

our $private = "This is a class level variable";

sub getattr {
    print "Inside the getattr function of Employee.pm module \n";
    $self = shift;
    $attr = shift;
    return ($self->{$attr});
}
1;
```

================

```
package Extend;

use base qw(Employee);

sub new {
    print "Inside new method of Employee.pm \n";
    my $class = shift;
    my %data = (
                name => shift,
                age => shift,
               );

    bless \%data , $class;
}

sub test {
    print "Inside test method of Extend class \n";
}

1;
```

==================

Now I have another piece of code which is using the Extend class :

```
use Extend;

my $obj = Extend->new("Subhayan",30);
my $value = $obj->getattr("age");
print ("The value of variable age is : $value \n");
$obj->test();
print "Do i get this : $obj.$private \n";
```

My question is regarding the variable $private defined in the parent class. As per my concept of inheritance attributes and methods of the parent class should be available through the subclass object . For example the function getattr runs fine . But why am I not being able to access $private variable using the base class Extend object .

What am I missing here ? Can someone please help ?

Comment: Note that your use of `Exporter` is incorrect here. Exporting and inheritance are two completely separate mechanisms, and if you're writing object-oriented code then you don't want `Exporter`. It's also probably better to write specific accessor methods for the public attributes, as your `getattr` allows direct access to all instance variables regardless of whether they are meant to be public or private. It's only a fractional improvement on writing `$obj->{'attr'}` in the calling code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables don't get inherited the same way subs do. To access it, you need to specify the entire package name (and yes, when you declare `$private`, you need `our`, not `my`):

```
print "$Employee::private\n";
```

It's much more robust to define accessor methods:

```
# Employee package
sub private {
    return $private;
}
```

...then in your script:

```
my $var = private();
```

To inherit object attributes from Employee, you can do:

```
# Employee

sub new {
    my $self = bless {
        dept => 'HR',
        hours => '9-5',
    }, shift;

    return $self;
}

# Extend

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new; # attrs inherited from Employee
    $self->{extended} = 1;
    return $self;
}

# script

my $extend = Extend->new;
```

Now `$extend` looks like:

```
{
    dept => 'HR',
    hours => '9-5',
    extended => 1,
}
```

You most likely wouldn't set dept or hours in the base class as it will apply to all employees, but I digress.

Comment: Helllo @Stevieb . Thanks for your response . Then how does inheriting attributes work in Perl . What are attributes of a class in Perl that can be inherited ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include one way to inherit object attributes.

Comment: Thanks @stevieb , but in the way you have shown we don't have to inherit the Employee class at all .if we replace $class->SUPER::new();  with Employee->new().  Apart from using SUPER and calling the superclass constructor is there no other way by which attributes are imported automatically the way methods are?

Comment: No. Without accessors, you'd have to export and import them. The `SUPER` package is just a convenience feature. If you ever change to a new base class, you don't have to change any code later. It's similar to the special `__PACKAGE__` variable.

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer helped me a lot.